# AppSettings in ASP.Net html file

Tags: asp.net, html, appsettings

I am trying to use the following but I keep getting an error or the href URL is not properly formed.
If I add the attribute : runat = 'server' then the page will not show an error, but the href will be exactly as in code below, rather than the first part of href being obtained from web.config. Any idea on how to make this work?

```
    <a href='<%$ AppSettings : MyAttribute%>/xyz/documents/ation_help.htm' 
       target="_blank">Help</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found worked for my situation was something very basic I did when developing with classic ASP and JSP. I tested the code with and without a master page, and it worked in both cases. Simply use **Response.Write** method. The code for this is as given below and it is placed in the child page. ***This approach will work always and requires no memorization of specialized ASP.Net expressions by the developer.*** Do I sound correct here OR am I missing something?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<div id="x" runat="server">
    <% Response.Write("<a href='" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAttribute"] + 
    "/xyz/documents/ation_help.htm' target='_blank'  >Help</a>"); %>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" text="<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>" />
```

You can find more info about expression builders from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)